# Разбиение библиотеки C# на отдельные DLL по функциональности

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Необходимо создать dll на C# с количеством функций 200 и более, разбитыми на группы по функциональности.

Вопросы:

1. Есть ли смысл создавать такую большую dll (группы разбиты на классы для удобства) или лучше создать свою dll для каждой группы?
2. На какие критерии ориентироваться при разбиении на dll?
3. Какие есть плюсы и минусы у разбиения?

Если можно, то поподробнее, с объяснением.

Comment: Вопрос не имеет решения в текущем виде. Само по себе число в 200 функций - это нормально, бывает и больше. Но принимать подобные решения на основе одного только числа функций - нельзя. Лучший способ организации кода зависит от задачи, которую он решает - а ее-то вы нам и не назвали.

Comment: Ну и смысл минусовать-закрывать? Нормальный вопрос, хоть и несколько общий. На него же можно нормально ответить. Для начинающих программистов такие вещи неочевидны, потому что факторов не один и не два.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбивать на разные динамические библиотеки имеет смысл, если вам это реально нужно. Возможные причины:

- **Разные приложения будут использовать разные библиотеки**, поэтому подключать к каждому монструозную библиотеку может быть нерационально. Чем больше библиотека, тем больше времени занимает JIT, тем медленнее скачивание и т. п.

  - Например, если вы поставляете библиотеку с помощью NuGet, то размер имеет значение, особенно если вы поставляете версии для разных версией .NET, что тоже заметно сказывается на размере.
  - С другой стороны, в каком-нибудь толстом приложении это имеет не такое большое значение, потому что толстый инсталлятор не будут скачивать через тонкий канал, инсталлятор может прогнать JIT при установке и т. п.
- Разделение на библиотеки и явное указание зависимостей между ними **заставляет разработчиков аккуратнее следить за разделением кода**. Если приложение разрабатывается большой командой разной степени профессионализма, то может быть удобно раскидать логические модели физически.

  - Например, при реализации паттерна MVVM явно выделить View в отдельную сборку, чтобы никто не смел добавлять зависимостей между View и Model.
  - С другой стороны, если приложение маленькое и разрабатывается одним-двумя разработчиками, то пользы от подобного деления будет мало, потому что один разработчик может держать всю архитектуру в голове.
- Если библиотеки имеют разные зависимости, то можно **разделить библиотеки по зависимостям**.

  - Например, если одна часть кода зависит от SQLite, другая требует Autofac, а третья работает на одном фреймворке .NET, то рационально разделить библиотеку на части, чтобы зависящие от библиотеки приложения не были вынуждены тащить с собой базы данных и пакеты NuGet, которые им не нужны.
  - С другой стороны, если зависимости отличаются только сборками из самого фреймворка, например, System.Xml и System.Net, то практической пользы от деления не будет никакого, потому что эти сборки доступны все, везде и сразу.

Не надо забывать и о минусах:

- Если библиотека одна, то она **быстрее компилируется и собирается**. Одна библиотека на 100 классов соберётся быстрее, чем 10 библиотк на 10 классов каждая.
- **Легче подключить одну библиотеку**, чем десять, и разруливать зависимости между ними и с внешними зависимостями.

P. S. 200 функций — это очень мало.

Comment: Спасибо, все предельно ясно.

Comment: А как тогда разбить функции в одной библиотеке на подгруппы (для удобства вызова из приложения)?

Comment: @Андрей С точки зрения файлов можно разбить код на иерархию папок в проекте по каким-то логическим частям. Например, в случае использования ООП можно разбить по иерархиям классов, отделить interop, сгруппировать по назначению и функциональности. / С точки зрения кода классы можно разбить на пространства имён (namespace). Visual Studio генерирует пространства имён по папкам, но это не всегда рационально, потому что пространств имён можно получиться многовато, и для вызывающего кода это может быть неудобно.

Comment: @Андрей В целом, факторов много, зависит от предпочтений. Не забивайте голову организацией кода по проектам, папкам и пространствам имён — это не главное его качество. Со временем разберётесь сами и определитесь с предпочтениями.

Comment: *прогнать JIT при установке* Возможно Вы имели в виду NGEN, а не JIT.

Comment: @PetSerAl NGEN и гоняет тот же компилятор в машинные коды, что и JIT, не?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что JIT компиляция не сохраняет результат своей работы в виде файла, пригодного для повторного использования, поэтому просто так прогонять JIT компиляцию несколько бессмысленно. На счёт того, гоняет ли NGEN и JIT один и тот же компилятор в машинные коды, в такие подробности не вдавался, так что ответить на это не могу. Но учитывая, что .NET включает в несколько JIT компиляторов (старый JIT и новый RyuJIT), то вполне возможно, что и NGEN имеет свой отдельный компилятор.

Comment: @Discord string interning чуть по-другому обрабатывается при прогоне ngen. больше вроде никаких отличий нет

Comment: Спасибо всем. Но возник доп. вопрос:

Comment: Правильно ли использовать дерево dll (уменьшается ли скорость обработки, т.е. переходов между библиотеками по сравнению, если бы все было-бы в одной библиотеке): А именно: есть главная dll, ее используют еще 3 dll. А уже в свою очередь приложение использует эти  3 dll. Надеюсь понятно...

Comment: @Андрей На данном этапе вы не столкнётесь с ситуацией, когда вызовы будут узким местом. Не занимайтесь микрооптимизацией.